Deadlock detected error while using @fieldParentPtr in Zig programming
I am trying to use some trick to have interface behavior using Zig programming. Here is the example code where I want to use Dog struct properties in a function which is being called on a different struct (Animal), I am able to access the property value (name) but when the value is used in std.debug.print, such as std.debug.print("{s}",.{self.name}); an error about deadlock detected is thrown.
The following is some text from the error message:
thread 17672 panic: Deadlock detected
C:\Software\Zig\Zig12Dev\zig\lib\std\Thread\Mutex.zig:45:19: 0xde2de4 in lock (zoo_example.exe.obj)
    self.impl.lock();
                  ^
C:\Software\Zig\Zig12Dev\zig\lib\std\debug.zig:85:22: 0xde34cb in print__anon_7068 (zoo_example.exe.obj)
    stderr_mutex.lock();
                     ^
C:\Software\Zig\Zig12Dev\zig\lib\std\os\windows.zig:2688:24: 0xdb234f in unexpectedError (zoo_example.exe.obj)
        std.debug.print("error.Unexpected: GetLastError({}): {}\n", .{
....
....

const std = @import("std");
      
const Animal = struct{
    walkfn : *const fn(*const Animal,u32) anyerror!void,
    fn walk(self:*const Animal,speed:u32) !void{
        return self.walkfn(self,speed);
    }
};
      
const Dog = struct{
    animal:Animal = Animal{.walkfn = walk},
    name:[]const u8,
    fn walk(animal:*const Animal,speed:u32) !void{  
        const self = @fieldParentPtr(Dog,"animal",animal);
        const _name = self.name;
        std.debug.print("{s} is walking with {d} miles/hr\n",.{_name,speed});
    }
};
  
const Cat = struct{
    animal:Animal = Animal{.walkfn = walk},
    fn walk(_:*const Animal,speed:u32) !void{
        std.debug.print("cat is walking with {d} miles/hr\n",.{speed});
    }
};

      
pub fn main() !void{
    const animals:[2]Animal = [_]Animal{(Dog{.name="Buddy"}).animal,(Cat{}).animal};
    for (animals) |animal|{
        try animal.walk(12);
    }
}

This is the solution to achieve the required interface behavior.
const std = @import("std");
      
const Animal = struct{
    ptr: *anyopaque,
    walkfn: *const fn(ptr:*anyopaque,speed:u32) anyerror!void,
          
    fn walk(animal:Animal,speed:u32) !void{
        try animal.walkfn(animal.ptr,speed);
    }
};
      
      
const Dog = struct{
    age:u32,
              
    fn walk(ptr:*anyopaque,speed:u32) !void{
        const self:*Dog = @ptrCast(@alignCast(ptr));
        std.debug.print("dog is {d} years old and is walking with speed {d}\n",.{self.age,speed});
    }
          
    fn animal(self:*Dog) Animal{
        return .{.ptr = self, .walkfn = walk};
    }
};

const Cat = struct{
    color:[]const u8,
    
    fn walk(ptr:*anyopaque,speed:u32) !void{
        const self:*Cat = @ptrCast(@alignCast(ptr));
        std.debug.print("cat with color {s} is walking with speed {d}\n",.{self.color,speed});
    }
    
    fn animal(self:*Cat) Animal{
        return .{.ptr = self,.walkfn = walk};
    }
};

const AnimalWalker = struct{
    fn walk(animal:Animal) !void{
        try animal.walk(20);
    }
};
      
pub fn main() !void{
    var dog = Dog{.age=12};
    var cat = Cat{.color="grey"};
    const animals:[2]Animal = [_]Animal{dog.animal(),cat.animal()};
    for (animals) |animal|{
        try animal.walk(123);
    }
}


looks like you have a race condition from multiple calls to std.debug.print - which tries to protect stderr with a mutex. That also tends to happen if you put std.debug.print statements in tests which, if ran by the default test runner, run on multiple threads.

Thanks for your help! I could achieve what I wanted with a great post found here at https://www.openmymind.net/Zig-Interfaces/. Learning zig is really a fun.

@gmcoding Can you post answer with code to your question?

@rofrol the solution code to my problem is added in the edited answer.

@gmcoding You could also take a look at Ziglings exercise #92: https://codeberg.org/ziglings/exercises/src/branch/main/exercises/092_interfaces.zig
There we have a similar approach.

@FObersteiner  Having std.debug.print protected by a mutex makes total sense, but what is confusing how could that cause a deadlock?.  Unless std.debug.print is locking twice,  the flow should be  Thread's A,B.    A.lock, A.Print, B.lock(wait), A.unlock, B.Print, B.unlock.   Or is @import("builtin").single_threaded been set, and the tests don't check this?.  Just curious, as I'm new to Zig.

@Keith good question; tbh I still feel like scratching the surface of Zig. didn't have the time to go deeper, especially multithreading. Can't even tell if it's one thread that locks itself or multiple threads that deadlock due to some ordering mischief of the locks...
